# TranSfering project in visual studio 2010 to another computer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, include, copy

I have a project in VS2010 that I want to transfer it's have a lot of files does there a easy way to know all the includes that project needs?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project + Properties, C/C++, Advanced, Show Includes = Yes.  Beware that it is noisy.